# Importing JSON data to Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have imported 3 rows to Postgres table called cards. When I am showing the contents of the table, some null values and raw text are coming in front of data.

Don't know why??

Does anybody has the idea??

[Here, the image attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DRjL.png)

Answer (score 2):

Someone put them there. Data gets there because someone put it there. We can't audit your system with three sentences.

Comment: The answer is gold.